# Notation for idele group?

Tags: number-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory

Which notation is better(or more standard) for the idele of a number field $K$?

$\mathbb{I}_K$ or $\mathbb{A}^\times_K$?

$\mathbb{I}_K$ is used in Milne's class field theory and has the advantage that it is a "thick" fractional ideal group $I_K$.

$\mathbb{A}^\times_K$ has the advantage that it is the group of units of adele ring.

Comment: There is also $GL_1(\mathbb{A}_K)$ which is widely used in the theory of automorphic representations

Comment: I tend to see $\mathbb A_K^\times$ more than I see $\mathbb I_K$, but both are used.